# How to use mpeg.org's mpeg2v12 decoder API?

Tags: c, decoder, mpeg-2

I have downloaded mpeg.org standard codec source code mpeg2v12 from
http://www.mpeg.org/MPEG/video/mssg-free-mpeg-software.html
I am now looking for examples of how to use it's decoder API to read some mpeg2 file. I appreciate any code sample you can provide. Thanks in advance.

Artur

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the correct answer is *You cannot do this!*.

MSSG's code is stand alone application and not a decoder as a re-entrant library so it cannot be used by linking from other application.

You can however use [libmpeg2](http://libmpeg2.sourceforge.net/). This is relatively easy to integrate with application and fully compliant.